# Create rails index to multi-column query with daterange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I am having some performance problems with this two queries:

```
any_impression = Impression.exists?(user_id: user_id, created_at: range)
any_visit      = Visit.exists?(user_id: user_id, created_at: range)
```

They have about 500k of records for each user and are taking more than 15s to run.

Based on this I would like to create two indexes, one for each search.

My question is, the indexes I should create are:

```
add_index :visits, [:user_id, :created_at]
add_index :impressions, [:user_id, :created_at]
```

Or need more some specific information to queries above use the indexes created ?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those indexes should be fine. In Postgres an index doesn't always know how to use a given operator---it depends on the index type. [This page from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html) explains the details.

Your proposed indexes would be btree indexes. In my experiments, telling ActiveRecord to query a timestamp column based on a range produces `BETWEEN ... AND ...` SQL:

```
User.where(created_at: (Date.parse('2015-01-01') ..
                        Date.parse('2016-01-01'))).to_sql
```

gives:

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM   "users"
WHERE  ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01')
```

Is that what you're seeing also? Then Postgres should use your index, because `BETWEEN` is just `<=` and `>=`.

You could also run the query by hand with `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see if the index is used as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and links are very useful. I create the index and the queries are running in few ms now, unbelievable and very very efficient, anyway, thanks much again =D.